# Choose from values in dropdown 2 based on choice in dropdown 1 in Sharepoint

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am trying to have the options available of dropdown 2 field change depending on the choice of the user from dropdown 1 in a SharePoint list or library. I've found vague solutions online recommending using Jquery (or infopath but that's not available for use in SharePoint anymore I think), but these are based on older versions of SharePoint. To clarify:

Drop down 1 values: A B C

Drop down 2 values: 1 2 3 4 5 6

If a user selects A in dropdown 1, then they would only be able to choose between 1 and 2 in dropdown 2. If a user selects B in dropdown 1, then they would only be able to choose between 3 and 4 in dropdown 2, and so forth.

I want to know how to be able to implement this functionality on a current day SharePoint site, whether through a list or a library (not positive if this would make a difference). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add an event handler for the onchange event to your first drop down, then change the options in drop down 2, you can use plain javascript or import JQuery, either one can do the job. IF you need to post back to the server to get the filtered results for dropdown2 you can then use Ajax.

Comment: @RyanWilson Sorry I have a pretty rudimentary view when it comes to implementing code with Sharepoint specifically. How would I specifically go about adding an event handler for the on change event?

Comment: Are you actually writing a script inside a .js file?

Comment: You can do Cascading dropdown using SPServices library. [https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195644/cascading-drop-down-in-sharepoint-online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195644/cascading-drop-down-in-sharepoint-online)